# count down timer in shopify app development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, shopify, shopify-app

I'm a newbie in Shopify apps development. I want to create an app countdown timer. I follow all the steps of `Build a Shopify app with Node and React` where I learn some basic concepts like retrieve data from `graghql` (query/mutation) and discount the products. My question is what is the next step for my app to save `countdown timer` for my selected products and display on front below the `add to cart button`. Where I save my code to display on the front side.

Comment: Please add what you have done so far

Comment: I've just followed the steps of this tutorial https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/set-up-your-app

Comment: In here we are supposed to post images, links etc.. show us what you have done so far and we could help you with the issues you are facing. Here we are not supposed to 'DO' things, we are here to 'FIX' error

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't think this platform is only for fixing the errors. If someone needs a guide and help, that must be an encouragement

Comment: you can reach here for guidance and support https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

to add your counter you need to inject your js to shopify store.

for this you need to make use of [Script Tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag)

And if you want to add some liquid stuff using app then you need to use [themes API.](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/theme)